# Porque usamos a palavra 'valor' na função?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Porque usamos a palavra 'valor' na função?

```
this.x.subscribe(valor => {
        if(valor){
          alert(1);
        } else{
          alert(2);
        }
      });
```

Ela pode ser substituída por qualquer outra palavra?

Comment: Isto é uma função, logo valor é um parametro e pode ter qualquer nome, mas, pq não testou pra ver o que acontece se trocar o nome?

Comment: Acredito que a dúvida dele é na sintaxe da arrow function.

Answer (score 3):

O `valor` é o nome de uma variável que é parâmetro de uma [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Observe que o `subscribe` recebe uma função callback como parâmetro, que tradicionalmente seria escrita como:

```
function nome(qualquernome) { 
  // faz alguma coisa 
}
```

Mas a forma que foi usada no seu exemplo é uma forma resumida. Por isso, como valor se trata de um parâmetro, ele pode ter qualquer nome na arrow function:

```
this.x.subscribe(qualquernome => {
  if(qualquernome){
    alert(1);
  } else{
      alert(2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

O valor é uma variável interna da função, poderia ser qualquer nome, ela espera receber um elemento para trabalhar em cima dele, no caso o valor, essa variável pode ser usada dentro da função para trabalhar o retorno dela.